# Can a GET parameter start with _?

Tags: php, request, character

Long story short, here's what happens.
I'm trying to make a GET request like this:

```
example.com/file.php?parameter=_v
```

The result is a 500 internal server error.

```
?parameter=v_
```

works just fine. Also,

```
?parameter=+01
```

works fine as well.

I'm sure that there's no problem with my script. Also, there's no rewrite rule in place at the moment.

So what can it be? Is it the server, or am I trying to achieve something that isn't allowed?

Comment: not any problem with ?parameter=_v  looks like file.php issue

Comment: There must be something wrong with your server. I can send such a $_GET without errors.

Comment: from php.net: Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced [...] so it won't fix my problem.

Comment: `_` is allowed n `GET` params.. the error is caused by something different..

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I thought. I can't even do 'echo $parameter', i still get the error. I will issue a ticket.

Comment: Hi, please post a code of php, then we are easy to find out your problem

Comment: It's probably worth showing the PHP file you are having problems with, before raising a PHP bug ticket - there may be something you overlooked. Since this is from February, would you add a answer to explain how this was resolved?